# \fi error in \afterenvironment hook in etoolbox package

Tags: errors

It's probably etoolbox or expl3 issue and i dont know,how to solve it. I compile document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\test}[1][true]{
\str_case:nnF {#1}{
{true}
{\message{true}
}
}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\test}
\begin{equation}
0
\end{equation}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

and get an error:
! Extra \fi.
\end ...if@ignore @ignorefalse \ignorespaces \fi

l.15 \end{equation}
Help me please solve this problem. Thanks everybody for any help.

Comment: What's the purpose of a command with an optional argument when the command is never explicitly used because buried in `\AfterEndEnvironment`?

Comment: Please, remove the tick from Ulrike's answer, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was wrong. Use @egreg's answer instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now it works ok,but i am not understoode,why in \BeforeBeginEnvironment{} it works without {},and \AfterEndEnvironment works only if command have {}?

Comment: I didn't look. It is simply dangerous to have a command which looks ahead in such hooks.

Comment: Sorry, but the diagnosis was wrong and the patient died. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg oh yes  ;-) But the system doesn't allow me to delete ;-(

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use `\str_case:nnF`, but only supply *two* arguments to it instead of the three is requires, so one more is looked for.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\test}[1][true]{
\str_case:nn {#1}{
{true}
{\message{true}
}
}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\test}
\begin{equation}
0
\end{equation}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

With cleaner coding and `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{O{true}}
 {
  \str_case:nn {#1}
   {
    {true}{\message{true}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\test}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

One of the strong points of the `expl3` language is that every function has a signature that explains how many arguments it expects and also their nature. Well, there's the `w` specifier, but this is usually relegated to internal code, not higher level code.

The two main argument specifiers are `N` and `n`: the former denotes that the function expects an argument consisting of a single token, the latter specifies an argument in braces.

Next come the `T` and `F` specifiers, that are very similar to `n`, that is, a braced argument is expected; such specifiers are used for functions that do conditional branching.

Other argument specifiers are `c`, `o`, `V`, `v`, `e`, `f` and `x`, that can only appear in signatures defined through `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`:

- `c` specifies a braced argument from which a control sequence name will be formed;
- `o` specifies a braced argument the contents of which will be expanded once before being passed to the main function;
- `V` specifies a single token (unbraced) argument that should be a variable name floating point); the value of the variable will be passed as a braced argument to the main function;
- `v` is like `V`, but the argument should be braced; a variable name will be formed and after that the behavior will be the same as `V`;
- `e`, `f` and `x` specify braced arguments that will be expanded prior to being passed to the main function.

So in your case the `\str_case:nnF` function expects *three* arguments. TeX will be looking for the third one and the result can be arbitrary rubbish, depending on what follows in the main input stream. By pure chance, calling your `\test` macro in `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` doesn't break things.